# How can I write $e^{ki\theta}/k$ as a nice integral?

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos\left(k\theta\right)}{k}$$ using $\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{ki\theta}/k$ as a first step. I recognize this as being similar to $\log\left(1-e^{i\theta}\right)$ plus some terms for sufficiently large $n;$ however, I am tempted to write $$i\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e^{ki\theta}}{ik}=i\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(-\int^{+\infty}_{\theta}e^{ki\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\right)$$ and then replace the sum and the integral with justification, but I'm not sure the improper integral converges. A careful analysis on the improper integral yields $$-\int^{+\infty}_{\theta}e^{ki\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha=-\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\int^{b}_{\theta}e^{ki\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha=\frac{1}{ik}\left[\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{ki\theta}-e^{kib}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{ik}\left[e^{ki\theta}-\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{kib}\right)\right]$$ and I'm stuck here. I'm not sure how to evaluate $$\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{kib}\right)$$ for a couple of reasons. First, I know that if $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R},$ then $\left|e^{kib}\right|\leq1.$ It seems that whenever $b$ is close enough to $2t\pi$ ($t$ integer), $\left|e^{kib}\right|$ approches $1.$ In my mind, a graph of $f(x)=\left|e^{kib}\right|$ would sporadically get close to one. For my assumption to behold, I need $\displaystyle\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{kib}\right)=0.$ My guts say maybe it is right, but I don't know how to properly justify it. It seems like the limit can be $1,$ another complex number or simply doesn't exist.

**So, how can I formally show what $\displaystyle\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{kib}\right)$ is? 
If $\displaystyle\lim_{b\rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{kib}\right)\neq0,$ is there another integral that nicely fits this situation?**

Comment: $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikb}$ is a complex number which travels around the unit circle with a speed $k$ and does not have a limit as $b\to\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints: we have that 
$$ 
  \sum_k \frac{\cos (k\theta)}{k} = \Re\left(\sum_k \frac{\exp (\mathrm ik\theta)}{k}\right)
$$
so that we only have to compute the latter sum. Let 
$$
  f(\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\exp (\mathrm ik\theta)}{k},
$$
then 
$$
  f'(\theta) = \mathrm i\sum_{k=1}^n \exp (\mathrm ik\theta) = \mathrm i \frac{\exp(\mathrm i(k+1)\theta) -1}{\exp(\mathrm i\theta) - 1}.
$$
Please tell me if you need some guidelines for the next steps.

Comment: I know it, and that's why I was hoping to find $\int_a^be^{ki\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha$ and find $a$ and $b$ in way that there's no constants hanging around. Which limits of integration should I take?

Comment: So you need to find a function $g(\theta)$ such that $g'(\theta) = \mathrm e^{\mathrm i k\theta}$, right? Then by Newton-Leibniz *any* integral works which has $\theta$ as the *upper limit*, e.g.
$$
  g(\theta) = \int_0^\theta \mathrm e^{\mathrm i ks} \mathrm ds
$$

Comment: I was confused with it because it will lead me to $$\int_0^{\theta}e^{kis} \mathrm ds=\frac{e^{ki\theta}}{ik} - \frac{1}{ik},$$ and the latter term diverges in a sum where $n\rightarrow\infty,$ (which I am studying simultaneously) but it's not the case. Thank you.

Comment: @Ilya:so to get $Re(f(\theta))$ do I need to integrate something like  $\int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{d \eta}{1-e^{-i \eta}}$ (from the expression for $f'(\theta))$?

Comment: @Alex: together with another exponent in the numerator, or to take a real part before integration

Comment: @Ilya: OK, so I get something like (probably not screamingly rigorously though) $Re \bigg( \int_{0}^{\theta}\frac{e^{-i \eta} d \eta}{1-e^{-i \eta}} \bigg) =\int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{\cos \eta-1}{\sin^{2} \eta+(1-\cos \eta)^2} d \eta = \frac{\theta}{2}$. Somthing along these lines?

Comment: @Ilya: One more question, if you don't mind (sorry I'm weak with complex analysis): here I used $Re(h(g(x))=h(Re(g(x))$. Is there a proof available for this property?

Comment: @Alex: there is just function necessary to encode this property, but it does not hold, e.g. 
$$
  \Re\left(\frac1z\right) = \frac{\Re(z)}{|z|^2}\neq \frac{1}{\Re(z)}.
$$
I would suggest you to use $\Re(z) = \frac12(z+\bar z)$ and the properties of the complex conjugation $\bar\cdot$

Comment: @Ilya: OK thanks